# The collection has not been initialized

Tags: javascript, office-365, jsom

I am having big issue with this code and I already did my best and searched for many solutions, i think the issue is regarding the execution timing or something.

anyway this is the error I am facing : 
**Uncaught Error: The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.**

and this is the code

```
function GetMyTasksListList(itemId) {
    var clientContextMyTasksListList = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();


    var MyTasksListList = clientContextMyTasksListList.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('All Tasks');



    //Start
    var MyTasksListcamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    MyTasksListcamlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Subject_x003a_ID"></FieldRef><Value Type="Text">' + itemId + '</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'ID\' Ascending=\'FALSE\' /></OrderBy></Query></View>');

    //END

    this.MyTasksListcollListItem = MyTasksListList.getItems(MyTasksListcamlQuery);



    //clientContextMyTasksListList.load(MyTasksListcollListItem);
    clientContextMyTasksListList.load(MyTasksListcollListItem, 'Include(Title,ID,Created,Author)');


    clientContextMyTasksListList.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onMyTasksListQuerySucceeded),


        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onMyTasksListQueryFailed)
    );


}
function onMyTasksListQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var MyTasksListlistItemEnum = MyTasksListcollListItem.getEnumerator();

    var count = MyTasksListcollListItem.get_count();
    var TaskatIDS = [];



    var MyTasksListList = '';
    if (count > 0) {
        while (MyTasksListlistItemEnum.moveNext()) {
            var MyTasksListListItem = MyTasksListlistItemEnum.get_current();

            var MyTasksListTitle = MyTasksListListItem.get_item("Title");
            //var MyTasksNots = MyTasksListListItem.get_item("Notes");
            var MyTasksListCreatedDate = new Date(MyTasksListListItem.get_item("Created"));

            //var userName = MyTasksListListItem.get_item("AssignedTo");//replace AssignedTo with your person column
            //var user = web.ensureUser(userName);
            //var email = user.get_email();
            //var loginName = user.get_loginName();
            var TaskId = MyTasksListListItem.get_item('ID');
            TaskatIDS.push(TaskId);
            var Author = MyTasksListListItem.get_item("Author");

            MyTasksListList += '<tr>' +
                //'<td>' + TaskId + '</td>' +
                '<td rowspan="2"><a href="https://Hajjaj.sharepoint.com/sites/TMS/Lists/All%20Tasks/EditForm.aspx?ID=' + TaskId + '&Source=https://Hajjaj.sharepoint.com/sites/TMS/Pages/Dashboard.aspx" target="_self" class="btn btn-group btn-sm tipb" data-original-title="Edit Task" style="border:1px solid #dddddd; padding:5px 7px 2px 7px; margin:5px" > <span class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:15px"></span> </a></td>' +
                '<td>' + MyTasksListTitle + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + MyTasksListCreatedDate.toDateString() + '</td>' +
                '<td><a href="#" class="text-info">' + Author.get_lookupValue() + '</a></td>' +                
                '<td><a href="https://Hajjaj.sharepoint.com/sites/TMS/Documents/Forms/Tasks_Documents_List.aspx?taskID=' + TaskId + '" target="_blank" class="btn btn-group btn-sm tipb" data-original-title="View Documents" style="border:1px solid #dddddd; padding:5px 7px 2px 7px; margin:5px" > <span class="fa fa-file-text" style="font-size:15px"></span> </a>' + 
                '<a href="javascript:GetCEONotesList('+TaskId+');" target="_blank" class="btn btn-group btn-sm tipb" data-original-title="View Documents" style="border:1px solid #dddddd; padding:5px 7px 2px 7px; margin:5px" > <span class="fa fa-eye" style="font-size:15px"></span> </a></td > ' +
                '</tr>' +
                '<tr><td colspan="4"> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; border:2px solid #eee" class="table" id="CEONotes' + TaskId + '"></table> </td></tr >';


        }        
    }

    else {
        MyTasksListList += '<tr><td colspan="6">No Tasks Related to this subject yet</td></tr>';
    }
    $('#MyTasksListContainer').html(MyTasksListList);

    var TaskatIDSarrayLength = TaskatIDS.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < TaskatIDSarrayLength; i++) {
        alert(TaskatIDS[i]);

        GetCEONotesList(TaskId);
    }

        //MyTasksListList += '';
        //$('#MyTasksListContainer').html(MyTasksListList);

        //notify_i('Info', 'What\'s Next Updated');

}
function onMyTasksListQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    notify_e('Request failed', args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------
//           CEONotes List Retrival
//-----------------------------------------------------------

function GetCEONotesList(TaskId) {
    var clientContextCEONotesList = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var CEONotesList = clientContextCEONotesList.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CEONotes');
    //Start
    var CEONotescamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    CEONotescamlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Task_x003a_ID"></FieldRef><Value Type="Text">' + TaskId + '</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'ID\' Ascending=\'FALSE\' /></OrderBy></Query></View>');

    //END

    this.CEONotescollListItem = CEONotesList.getItems(CEONotescamlQuery);



    clientContextCEONotesList.load(CEONotescollListItem, 'Include(Title, Id,Task_x003a_ID,Created)');


    clientContextCEONotesList.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCEONotesQuerySucceeded),


        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onCEONotesQueryFailed)
    );


}
function onCEONotesQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var CEONoteslistItemEnum = CEONotescollListItem.getEnumerator();

    var count = CEONotescollListItem.get_count();

    //alert(count);
    var target = "";
    var CEONotesList = '<tr><th colspan="3">CEO Note</th><th>Date</th></tr>';
    if (count > 0) {
        while (CEONoteslistItemEnum.moveNext()) {
            var CEONotesListItem = CEONoteslistItemEnum.get_current();
            var CEONotesTitle = CEONotesListItem.get_item("Title");
            var CEONotesCreatedDate = new Date(CEONotesListItem.get_item("Created"));
            target = CEONotesListItem.get_item("Task_x003a_ID").get_lookupValue();
            target = "#CEONotes" + target;
            //alert(target);
            CEONotesList += '<tr><td colspan="3">' + CEONotesTitle + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + CEONotesCreatedDate.toDateString() + '</td></tr>';
        }
    }

    else {
        CEONotesList += '<tr><td colspan="6">No comment Related to this subject yet</td></tr>';
    }

        CEONotesList += '';
        //salert("last:" + target +"Code"+ CEONotesList);
        $(target).html(CEONotesList);

    //notify_i('Info', 'What\'s Next Updated');

}
function onCEONotesQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    notify_e('Request failed', args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scope conflict in code, so the (this) value in the ListItemCollection  is not what you are expecting. So, you can try the below code. I have removed the `this` and replaced it with var. Also removed `function.createdelegate` as its not needed.

```
function GetMyTasksListList(itemId) {
    var clientContextMyTasksListList = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    var MyTasksListList = clientContextMyTasksListList.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('All Tasks');

    //Start
    var MyTasksListcamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    MyTasksListcamlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Subject_x003a_ID"></FieldRef><Value Type="Text">' + itemId + '</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'ID\' Ascending=\'FALSE\' /></OrderBy></Query></View>');

    //END

    var MyTasksListcollListItem = MyTasksListList.getItems(MyTasksListcamlQuery);

    //clientContextMyTasksListList.load(MyTasksListcollListItem);
    clientContextMyTasksListList.load(MyTasksListcollListItem, 'Include(Title,ID,Created,Author)');

    //clientContextMyTasksListList.executeQueryAsync(onMyTasksListQuerySucceeded,onMyTasksListQueryFailed);

    clientContextMyTasksListList.executeQueryAsync(function(){
            var MyTasksListlistItemEnum = MyTasksListcollListItem.getEnumerator();

            var count = MyTasksListcollListItem.get_count();
            var TaskatIDS = [];



            var MyTasksListList = '';
            if (count > 0) {
                while (MyTasksListlistItemEnum.moveNext()) {
                    var MyTasksListListItem = MyTasksListlistItemEnum.get_current();

                    var MyTasksListTitle = MyTasksListListItem.get_item("Title");
                    //var MyTasksNots = MyTasksListListItem.get_item("Notes");
                    var MyTasksListCreatedDate = new Date(MyTasksListListItem.get_item("Created"));

                    //var userName = MyTasksListListItem.get_item("AssignedTo");//replace AssignedTo with your person column
                    //var user = web.ensureUser(userName);
                    //var email = user.get_email();
                    //var loginName = user.get_loginName();
                    var TaskId = MyTasksListListItem.get_item('ID');
                    TaskatIDS.push(TaskId);
                    var Author = MyTasksListListItem.get_item("Author");

                    MyTasksListList += '<tr>' +
                        //'<td>' + TaskId + '</td>' +
                        '<td rowspan="2"><a href="https://Hajjaj.sharepoint.com/sites/TMS/Lists/All%20Tasks/EditForm.aspx?ID=' + TaskId + '&Source=https://Hajjaj.sharepoint.com/sites/TMS/Pages/Dashboard.aspx" target="_self" class="btn btn-group btn-sm tipb" data-original-title="Edit Task" style="border:1px solid #dddddd; padding:5px 7px 2px 7px; margin:5px" > <span class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:15px"></span> </a></td>' +
                        '<td>' + MyTasksListTitle + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + MyTasksListCreatedDate.toDateString() + '</td>' +
                        '<td><a href="#" class="text-info">' + Author.get_lookupValue() + '</a></td>' +                
                        '<td><a href="https://Hajjaj.sharepoint.com/sites/TMS/Documents/Forms/Tasks_Documents_List.aspx?taskID=' + TaskId + '" target="_blank" class="btn btn-group btn-sm tipb" data-original-title="View Documents" style="border:1px solid #dddddd; padding:5px 7px 2px 7px; margin:5px" > <span class="fa fa-file-text" style="font-size:15px"></span> </a>' + 
                        '<a href="javascript:GetCEONotesList('+TaskId+');" target="_blank" class="btn btn-group btn-sm tipb" data-original-title="View Documents" style="border:1px solid #dddddd; padding:5px 7px 2px 7px; margin:5px" > <span class="fa fa-eye" style="font-size:15px"></span> </a></td > ' +
                        '</tr>' +
                        '<tr><td colspan="4"> <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%; border:2px solid #eee" class="table" id="CEONotes' + TaskId + '"></table> </td></tr >';


                }        
            }

            else {
                MyTasksListList += '<tr><td colspan="6">No Tasks Related to this subject yet</td></tr>';
            }
            $('#MyTasksListContainer').html(MyTasksListList);

            var TaskatIDSarrayLength = TaskatIDS.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < TaskatIDSarrayLength; i++) {
                alert(TaskatIDS[i]);

                GetCEONotesList(TaskId);
            }

                //MyTasksListList += '';
                //$('#MyTasksListContainer').html(MyTasksListList);

                //notify_i('Info', 'What\'s Next Updated');
            },function(sender,args){
                notify_e('Request failed', args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());          
            });
}


//-----------------------------------------------------------
//           CEONotes List Retrival
//-----------------------------------------------------------

function GetCEONotesList(TaskId) {
    var clientContextCEONotesList = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var CEONotesList = clientContextCEONotesList.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('CEONotes');
    //Start
    var CEONotescamlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    CEONotescamlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Task_x003a_ID"></FieldRef><Value Type="Text">' + TaskId + '</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'ID\' Ascending=\'FALSE\' /></OrderBy></Query></View>');

    //END

    var CEONotescollListItem = CEONotesList.getItems(CEONotescamlQuery);



    clientContextCEONotesList.load(CEONotescollListItem, 'Include(Title, Id,Task_x003a_ID,Created)');


    //clientContextCEONotesList.executeQueryAsync(onCEONotesQuerySucceeded,onCEONotesQueryFailed);

    clientContextCEONotesList.executeQueryAsync(function(){
                var CEONoteslistItemEnum = CEONotescollListItem.getEnumerator();

                var count = CEONotescollListItem.get_count();

                //alert(count);
                var target = "";
                var CEONotesList = '<tr><th colspan="3">CEO Note</th><th>Date</th></tr>';
                if (count > 0) {
                    while (CEONoteslistItemEnum.moveNext()) {
                        var CEONotesListItem = CEONoteslistItemEnum.get_current();
                        var CEONotesTitle = CEONotesListItem.get_item("Title");
                        var CEONotesCreatedDate = new Date(CEONotesListItem.get_item("Created"));
                        target = CEONotesListItem.get_item("Task_x003a_ID").get_lookupValue();
                        target = "#CEONotes" + target;
                        //alert(target);
                        CEONotesList += '<tr><td colspan="3">' + CEONotesTitle + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + CEONotesCreatedDate.toDateString() + '</td></tr>';
                    }
                }

                else {
                    CEONotesList += '<tr><td colspan="6">No comment Related to this subject yet</td></tr>';
                }

                    CEONotesList += '';
                    //salert("last:" + target +"Code"+ CEONotesList);
                    $(target).html(CEONotesList);

                //notify_i('Info', 'What\'s Next Updated');
    },function(sender,args){
            notify_e('Request failed', args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    });
}
```

Comment: in this case another error is coming : Uncaught ReferenceError: MyTasksListcollListItem is not defined
    at Array.onMyTasksListQuerySucceeded (CustomCode.js:1322)

Comment: my bad, can you check with the updated code ?

Comment: thanks a lot dear , that solve the issue , many many thanks to you dear you saved me.